# Seek operation in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a scenarios to do some admin tasks with Kafka.

There is a topic A with 10 partitions. There are 5 different applications that consume the messages from topic A, each application (app1, app2, app3, app4, app5) has their own consumer "group.id" (group1, group2, group3, group4, group5) so each applications can work individually with their own offsets. auto offset commit is set to true. Number of consumers in the consumer group of each applications are different (like app1 has 10 consumers in group1, app2 has 5 consumers in group2).

Now the admin wants to,

case-1: forward the offset of app2 by 5 position from current offset position(X). For this task, should you stop app2 and create a single KafkaConsumer (not spring), with the group id same as of app2 which is "group2" and commit the new offset X+5 and start the app2?

case-2: forward the offset of all the applications of topic A by 5 position from their current offset position(X), assume all applications are at same offset X. For this task, should you stop all the applications and create a KafkaConsumer with empty group id "", and commit the new offset X+5 and start all the applications? or do similar to case-1 but for each applications individually?

Or is there any better way to do with kafka?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't `ConsumerSeekAware`  help you?

> In order to seek, your listener must implement `ConsumerSeekAware` which has the following methods:

```
void registerSeekCallback(ConsumerSeekCallback callback);

void onPartitionsAssigned(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback);

void onIdleContainer(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback);
```

> To arbitrarily seek at runtime, use the callback reference from the `registerSeekCallback` for the appropriate thread.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#seek

Comment: So, like in the question, to seek to X+5 position, I need to write X+5 logic in registerSeekCallback method. But when will this method (registerSeekCallback) be triggered?

Comment: And if you need to do the same X+5 when the app is stopped and the last committed offset is X, we have to do something like mentioned in the question right? or?

Comment: See JavaDocs of mentioned classes for more info. I’m not sure

Comment: When the consumer is stopped, you should consider to seek via `onPatitionsAssigned()`

Comment: Thank you! your point is correct. I just realized I cannot use spring kafka in all of my applications. Making the correction in the question. Thanks again.